# Mail.app reverts preference changes on restart - what can I do?

Tags: mail.app, email, preferences

I have a set of SmartMailboxes in mail.app and noticed after I change them and restart the program, the changes are lost.

I just tried deleting an old rule under Preferences > Rules and the rule returned when I restarted mail.app.

I have checked the preference files for obvious problems and searched online and on these forums, but can't find any clues.

Comment: Have you enabled syncing documents and data with iCloud? I think it also enables syncing smart mailboxes. You could try temporarily deleting `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/SmartMailboxesLocalProperties.plist`, `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/SyncedSmartMailboxes.plist`, or `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that and it reset my smart folders, but changes, again, were not saved when I restarted. Any other ideas?